# Sequence containing infinitely many composite numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Claim:

'Consider an infinite sequence of $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2},...$ integers that satisfy the conditions $a_{0}\geq 2$ and $a_{n+1}\in\{2a_{n}-1, 2a_{n}+1\}$ for all indices $n\geq 0$. Prove that each such sequence contains infinitely many composite numbers.'

Here's what I attempted:

We have a sequence
$a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n},a_{n+1},...$

And we know that

$a_{n+1}=2a_{n}-1 \wedge a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+1$

thus, for $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}-1$:

$a_{1}=2a_{0}-1$

$a_{2}=2(2a_{0}-1)-1=4a_{0}-3$

$a_{3}=2(4a_{0}-3)-1=8a_{0}-7$

where I noticed the pattern and got the following claim:

$a_{n}=2^{n}a_{0}-2^{n}-1$

And similarly would be with $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+1$

To prove it is a composite number, we only have to prove it's not a prime number. However, I'm unable to solve from here. (Also not sure whether my solution is right either.)

Could you provide me with your solution, please?

Comment: Your attempt to break it into two cases is not right. You can't assume that $a_{n+1}-2a_n$ is always $1$ or always $-1$--- it may use the $+1$ some indefinite number of times, then same with the $-1,$ etc, in a very unpredictable way.

Comment: This could even be an open problem. My guess is that the claim is true, but I have no idea for a proof.

Comment: @Peter I don't think to.  If you want to avoid having infinitely many multiples of 3 in the sequence, your choices for when to use $2a_n+1$ and $2a_n-1$ are very restricted. So restricted that it becomes predictable in fact.

Comment: Context matters.  Is there any reason to imagine that this has a pleasant solution?  Or any solution at all? Have you, say, tried to make a finite string of primes that satisfies your rule?  How long a string have you found?

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, it is trickier than I thought. If [Artin's conjecture on primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) is true for base 2, then we can pick a large enough prime with 2 as a primitive root, and show that infinitely terms are divisible by that prime.